# Price won't show up in the html parsing

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the price of this object into a variable and print it out/put it in a CSV.

This is the section of html that I am trying to parse:

```
<span class="price" data-js-product-price="">
 <span>$429.00 USD</span>
</span>
```

This is my python code (sorry im a little new to python and I've been trying to figure this out for a while, so sorry if the code is a little messy)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_to_scrape = "https://www.backfireboards.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwjtOTBhAvEiwASG4bCGHPgmV4XjyqAIFrW0Lr0IiW0AvfTiC7sZ4E-HtM_qJ9k4ahAu2CHxoCH5YQAvD_BwE"

request_page = urlopen(url_to_scrape)
page_html = request_page.read()
request_page.close()

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')

board_prices = html_soup.find_all('span', class_='price')

print("num of prices: " + str(len(board_prices)))
file_name = 'product.csv'
f = open(file_name,'w')

headers = 'Title, Price \n'

f.write(headers)

i = 1

for price in board_prices:
    currPrice = price.span.text
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    print(price)
    print(currPrice)


f.close()
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/isaiah/PycharmProjects/Web_scrape/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    currPrice = price.span.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I know this isn't a text object but when I print it without the .text it spits out this:

```
1
<span class="price" data-js-popup-cart-subtotal=""></span>
None
2
<span class="price" data-js-product-price=""><span></span></span>
<span></span>
3
<span class="price" data-js-product-price=""><span></span></span>
<span></span>
4
<span class="price"><span></span></span>
<span></span>
5
<span class="price" data-js-product-price=""><span></span></span>
<span></span>
6
<span class="price" data-js-product-price=""><span></span></span>
<span></span>
```

I don't know why the $429 is disappearing in the object, im a little new to webscraping and such. Is there something very simple I am ignorant too?

Also, from what I can tell the website actually has 8 prices listed on this page that i am pulling from yet the board_prices object is only size 6? Could someone explain that to me as well?

Comment: mille gracie for this question#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external source. To get titles/prices of electric skateboards you can use following example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.backfireboards.com/collections/electric-skateboards"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for h4 in soup.select(".product-collection__content h4"):
    title = h4.get_text(strip=True)
    price = h4.find_next(class_="price").contents[-1].text
    print("{:<15} {}".format(price, title))
```

Prints:

```
$429.00 USD     Backfire G2 Black with Super Power Hobbywing Motors and 96mm Wheels with 180 Days Warranty Especially Suitable for Beginners
$649.00 USD     Backfire G3 with Super Flexible Deck
$799.00 USD     Backfire Zealot S Belt Drive Electric Skateboard
$1,899.00 USD   Backfire Hammer Sledge
$1,199.00 USD   Backfire Hammer Belt Drive All Terrain Electric Skateboard
$649.00 USD     Backfire Zealot Belt Drive Electric Skateboard
$1,399.00 USD   Backfire Ranger X3 All Terrain Electric Skateboard with 1500W X2 Ultra High Power Ultra High Torque Motors and 12S High Voltage High Efficiency Electronic System
$999.00 USD     Backfire Ranger X2 All Terrain Electric Skateboard with 1200W X2 Ultra High Power Ultra High Torque Motors and 12S High Voltage High Efficiency Electronic System
$599.00 USD     Backfire Mini Super Portable Electric Skateboard Best for City Commute
$999.00 USD     Backfire G3 Plus with Carbon Fiber Deck and Ultra Long Range
$499.00 USD     Backfire ERA Electric Skateboard
```

Comment: Thank you so much, could I ask you some questions about your code? First of all, what does setting  ```strip = true``` do? Second, why do you look at the -1 th element in the contents of the next price content?

Comment: @JonathanDoe `strip=True` means that I want to strip whitespace characters from the string (similar to `str.strip`). `contents[-1]` means I want to get actual price (not the price before sale - it there is any)